# Springboot error reading environment variable on @PropertySource

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I am doing a Springboot application and I have externalized the configuration files. I develop the application on Windows 10 using Eclipse and runs on a Debian 9 server with Tomcat 8.

The path to the configuration files is defined on an environment variable named DDK_OPT. This variable is defined in "`/etc/environment`" as:

```
DDK_OPT=/opt/DDK
```

In my Springboot application I try to use it in the `@PropertySource` decorators:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"file:${DDK_OPT}/application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "eus.ddk.repository.APL", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "aplEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "aplTransactionManager"
)
public class APLPersistenceConfig {
...
```

When Tomcat starts, the application fails giving this error:

```
2019-01-09 11:37:23.610 [ERROR] SpringApplication.Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [eus.ddk.APLApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'DDK_OPT' in value "file:${DDK_OPT}/application.properties"
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:183) ~[ConfigurationClassParser.class:4.3.21.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.class:4.3.21.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.class:4.3.21.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272) ~[PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.class:4.3.21.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92) ~[PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.class:4.3.21.RELEASE]
...
```

On Windows the application runs perfectly but I can't get to make it work on the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think `DDK_OPT` is set on the server? Maybe it isn't? Have you checked that? Note that the use of PropertySource is not recommended, if you need to change the location of the configuration, there are other options described in the doc

Comment: As I said, the variable is set in `/etc/environment` and I have tried it doing `echo $DDK_OPT`, so I know it is there. To externalize the configuration I have done what the docs say: [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). If there is another recommended way of doing it, could you please point it out to me? Thanks!

Comment: `echo $DDK_OPT` validates that the property is available in your shell, it doesn't validate that it's available to the java process. Perhaps it's running as a different user? I don't see how the link you've referenced recommends the use of `PropertySource`. This is [the section I was referring to](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

Comment: Setting the variable in `/etc/environment` makes it available to all the users, indeed Tomcat runs with `tomcat8` user. I have tried with 3 different users on the server and all of them can see the variable, so I have to suppose that `tomcat8` user can also see it. The section you talk about says how to tell Springboot where the properties files are, but running them with `java` command and `jar` files. I'm using `war` files on a Tomcat 8 server so it doesn't apply to my case. The very beggining of that doc talks about how property sources are loaded and OS environment variables are number 10.

Comment: `PropertySource` is the name of the abstraction and that's what that doc talks about. I was talking about using `@PropertySource`, this is definitely not recommended and if you need to customize the location of the configuration, you shouldn't be using that but `spring.config.location` or a custom `EnvironmentPostProcessor`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the environment variable in `/etc/environment` I have set it on the `/etc/default/tomcat8` file and it started working as I wanted to.

Thanks for the help anyway Stephane!